# Input sliders , oninput with dynamic calculations

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a few issues with my code.
I want to be able to change the sliders and with javascript dynamically calculate and update the results. I can not get it to work as intended.

Problems:

- When I change the sliders, the addition, subtraction and division is not being calculated and the elements are not updated.
- When I manually change the sliders value by user keyboard input in the `inputs` with `type="number"`, the background of the slider and the `span` element with `class="range-slider__value"` is not updating. It is working as intended when i move the slider button.

Best regards,
Frank

```js
// colors of sliders
const settings={
  fill: '#1abc9c',
  background: '#d7dcdf'
}

// find all sliders
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider');

// Iterate through that list of sliders
Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders,(slider)=>{
  // Look inside slider for our input add an event listener
  slider.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (event)=>{
    // 1. apply value to the span
    slider.querySelector('span').innerHTML = event.target.value;
    // 2. applyfill to the input
    applyFill(event.target);
  });
  // Don't wait for the listener, apply it now.
  applyFill(slider.querySelector('input'));
});

// This function applies the fill to the sliders
function applyFill(slider) {
  // turn value into a percentage to figure out how far it is in between the min and max of our input
  const percentage = 100*(slider.value-slider.min)/(slider.max-slider.min);
  //  create a linear gradient that separates at the above point
  // background color will change here
  const bg = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${settings.fill} ${percentage}%, ${settings.background} ${percentage+0.1}%)`;
  slider.style.background = bg;
}



// Store input as vars and do math.
function updateValue() {
  var firstNum = document.querySelector('input[name=amountInput]').value;
  var secondNum = document.querySelector('input[name=amountInput]').value;
  var addition = firstNum + secondNum;
  var subtraction = firstNum - secondNum;
  var division = firstNum / secondNum;
  document.querySelector('.addition').innerHTML = addition;
  document.querySelector('.subtraction').innerHTML = subtraction;
  document.querySelector('.division').innerHTML = division;
}
function firstNumSliderChange(val) {
         document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = val;
         updateValue();
      }
function secondNumSliderChange(val) {
         document.querySelector('.output-two').innerHTML = val;
         updateValue();
      }
```

```css
h5 {margin:0;padding:0;}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width:250px;
  
}



.final-outputs {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  width:400px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #eee;
  padding:1rem;
}

.addition, .subtraction, .division {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:.1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
      <input class="output" type="number" name="amountInput" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form>
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
      <input class="output-two" type="number" name="amountInput" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="final-outputs">
    <div class="final-output final-output--add">
      <h5>addition</h5><span class="addition">1</span></div>
    <div class="final-output final-output--sub">
      <h5>subtraction</h5><span class="subtraction">2</span></div>
    <div class="final-output final-output--div">
      <h5>division</h5><span class="division">3</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Addition, subtraction and division is not being calculated as the firstNumSliderChange and the secondNumSliderChange functions are not getting invoked. You can trigger them on `onchange` event
2. background of the slider is not getting updated when you set the input.value. This is because, oninput event will not be triggered when you set the value programmatically. You can get the desired outcome by triggering the applyFill on amountInput `input` event. as below

```js
// colors of sliders
const settings = {
  fill: '#1abc9c',
  background: '#d7dcdf'
}

// Update the range value and applyFill
function updateRangeValue(range, newVal) {
  range.value = newVal;
  applyFill(range);
}

// find all sliders
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider');

// Iterate through that list of sliders
Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders, (slider) => {
  // Look inside slider for our input add an event listener
  slider.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    // 1. apply value to the span
    slider.querySelector('span').innerHTML = event.target.value;
    // 2. applyfill to the input
    applyFill(event.target);
  });
  // Don't wait for the listener, apply it now.
  applyFill(slider.querySelector('input'));
});

// This function applies the fill to the sliders
function applyFill(slider) {
  // turn value into a percentage to figure out how far it is in between the min and max of our input
  const percentage = 100 * (slider.value - slider.min) / (slider.max - slider.min);
  //  create a linear gradient that separates at the above point
  // background color will change here
  const bg = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${settings.fill} ${percentage}%, ${settings.background} ${percentage+0.1}%)`;
  slider.style.background = bg;
}



// Store input as vars and do math.
function updateValue() {
  var firstNum = document.querySelector('input[name=amountInput1]').value;
  var secondNum = document.querySelector('input[name=amountInput2]').value;
  var addition = firstNum + secondNum;
  var subtraction = firstNum - secondNum;
  var division = firstNum / secondNum;
  document.querySelector('.addition').innerHTML = addition;
  document.querySelector('.subtraction').innerHTML = subtraction;
  document.querySelector('.division').innerHTML = division;
}

function firstNumSliderChange(val) {
  document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = val;
  updateValue();
}

function secondNumSliderChange(val) {
  document.querySelector('.output-two').innerHTML = val;
  updateValue();
}
```

```css
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 250px;
}

.final-outputs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.addition,
.subtraction,
.division {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountInput1.value=this.value" onchange="firstNumSliderChange()" />
      <input class="output" type="number" name="amountInput1" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="updateRangeValue(this.form.amountRange, this.value)" />
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form>
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountInput2.value=this.value" onchange="secondNumSliderChange()" />
      <input class="output-two" type="number" name="amountInput2" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="updateRangeValue(this.form.amountRange, this.value)" />
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="final-outputs">
    <div class="final-output final-output--add">
      <h5>addition</h5><span class="addition">1</span></div>
    <div class="final-output final-output--sub">
      <h5>subtraction</h5><span class="subtraction">2</span></div>
    <div class="final-output final-output--div">
      <h5>division</h5><span class="division">3</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```